# MySql many to many search

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many, laravel-5

I'm having some issues wrapping my head around a many to many lookup. I've got the following tables:

```
mysql> desc tags;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra              |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| created_at | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                   |
| updated_at | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| user_id    | bigint(20)       | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| name       | varchar(64)      | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+

mysql> desc response_and_tag_relationships;
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| response_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| tag_id      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> desc survey_responses;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| created_at   | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| updated_at   | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| survey_id    | bigint(20)       | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| response     | text             | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| score        | smallint(6)      | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| recipient_id | bigint(20)       | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+

mysql> desc surveys;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| created_at   | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| updated_at   | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| survey_token | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| type         | smallint(6)      | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| name         | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+

mysql> desc people;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| created_at | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| updated_at | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| email      | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| last_sent  | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| name       | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| dob        | date             | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

And I need to group the tags featured within responses. So I've come up with the following SQL (with my limited knowledge), which, seems to do the job:

```
SELECT 
    rat.tag_id, 
    rat.response_id,
    t.name,
    sr.response,
    p.name,
    p.email
FROM 
    response_and_tag_relationships rat 
INNER JOIN tags t ON t.id=rat.tag_id 
INNER JOIN survey_responses sr ON sr.id=rat.response_id
INNER JOIN surveys s ON s.id = sr.survey_id
INNER JOIN people p ON p.id=sr.recipient_id
WHERE  
    t.name IN (SELECT name FROM tags);
```

And produces the following results:

```
+--------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| tag_id | response_id | name        | response                                                                                                                                                                                                                             | name                      | email                             |
+--------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|      1 |           1 | ex          | Repudiandae nam excepturi quasi perferendis nisi sint. Et excepturi id facere modi et sed. Eius nihil repellat veritatis voluptas.                                                                                                   | Miss Sally Breitenberg    | kkiehn@breitenberg.net            |
|      3 |           1 | repudiandae | Repudiandae nam excepturi quasi perferendis nisi sint. Et excepturi id facere modi et sed. Eius nihil repellat veritatis voluptas.                                                                                                   | Miss Sally Breitenberg    | kkiehn@breitenberg.net            |
|      4 |           1 | nam         | Repudiandae nam excepturi quasi perferendis nisi sint. Et excepturi id facere modi et sed. Eius nihil repellat veritatis voluptas.                                                                                                   | Miss Sally Breitenberg    | kkiehn@breitenberg.net            |
|      5 |           1 | excepturi   | Repudiandae nam excepturi quasi perferendis nisi sint. Et excepturi id facere modi et sed. Eius nihil repellat veritatis voluptas.                                                                                                   | Miss Sally Breitenberg    | kkiehn@breitenberg.net            |
|      6 |           1 | quasi       | Repudiandae nam excepturi quasi perferendis nisi sint. Et excepturi id facere modi et sed. Eius nihil repellat veritatis voluptas.                                                                                                   | Miss Sally Breitenberg    | kkiehn@breitenberg.net            |
|      7 |           1 | perferendis | Repudiandae nam excepturi quasi perferendis nisi sint. Et excepturi id facere modi et sed. Eius nihil repellat veritatis voluptas.                                                                                                   | Miss Sally Breitenberg    | kkiehn@breitenberg.net            |
|      8 |           1 | nisi        | Repudiandae nam excepturi quasi perferendis nisi sint. Et excepturi id facere modi et sed. Eius nihil repellat veritatis voluptas.                                                                                                   | Miss Sally Breitenberg    | kkiehn@breitenberg.net            |
|      9 |           1 | sint        | Repudiandae nam excepturi quasi perferendis nisi sint. Et excepturi id facere modi et sed. Eius nihil repellat veritatis voluptas.                                                                                                   | Miss Sally Breitenberg    | kkiehn@breitenberg.net            |
```

but I think I've got my logic backwards, as this is response driven, not tag driven (I think...). I basically, just need a list of tags that match the results to return in a responses call api method - So is there a better way to do this?

**Edit**

My ideal result would be (although I don't believe its possible):

```
+--------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| tag_id | response_id | name        | response                                                                                                                                                                                                                             | name                      | email                             |
+--------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|      1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 |           1 | ex          | Repudiandae nam excepturi quasi perferendis nisi sint. Et excepturi id facere modi et sed. Eius nihil repellat veritatis voluptas.                                                                                                   | Miss Sally Breitenberg    | kkiehn@breitenberg.net            |
```

I also need to construct this within Laravel eloquent orm, but I'm guessing just a raw query would be best

Comment: It would be great if you create fiddle on http://www.sqlfiddle.com with some sample data and the expected result out of those into the question.

Comment: I've done as you've requested, but I have no idea how to use that site - And when I run it, it just sits there. Hopefully you'll have more luck? :( http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06a0e/1/0

Comment: Yes the `inner joins` perhaps not getting matching data from joining tables. However it would be easy to debug the issue if you provide the expected result into the question from the data set.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok from the expected resultset its more like you are trying to group the tag ids , and yes you can do using the `group_concat` function as

```
SELECT 
    group_concat(rat.tag_id) as tag_ids, 
    rat.response_id,
    t.name,
    sr.response,
    p.name,
    p.email
FROM 
    response_and_tag_relationships rat 
INNER JOIN tags t ON t.id=rat.tag_id 
INNER JOIN survey_responses sr ON sr.id=rat.response_id
INNER JOIN surveys s ON s.id = sr.survey_id
INNER JOIN people p ON p.id=sr.recipient_id
group by rat.response_id
```

Now the above query for each different `response_id` will group the `tag_id` as comma separated string.

Also note that when using `group by`  and selecting data from many to many may return any random value, for example if we keep  `t.name` in the selection then it might be any one from many to many relation after doing the join and same for other values.

Ideally you should never select those columns in these situation or use them in the aggregate function like `group_concat`. The ideal query would be

```
SELECT 
        group_concat(rat.tag_id) as tag_ids, 
        rat.response_id
    FROM 
        response_and_tag_relationships rat 
    INNER JOIN tags t ON t.id=rat.tag_id 
    INNER JOIN survey_responses sr ON sr.id=rat.response_id
    INNER JOIN surveys s ON s.id = sr.survey_id
    INNER JOIN people p ON p.id=sr.recipient_id
    group by rat.response_id
```

If you need other columns in the select as well then as mentioned before it might be any random value from the joined data. If you want all then use `group_concat()` for each of them.

Check the manual for [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) since for large data set you may need to increase `group_concat_max_len`